# What is the nature of the series $\sum \frac{5^n - 3^n}{3^n + n^4 } $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> What is the nature of the series with the general term $u_n = \frac{5^n - 3^n}{3^n + n^4 } $ ?

---

I have tried to find an inequality from which I can derive the convergence or non convergence of the serie but I could not progress much beyond: 
$ u_n \geq \frac{5^n}{3^n + n^4 } \ge \frac{3^n}{3^n + n^4 } $

And: $\lim  \frac{3^n}{3^n + n^4 }  = 1$

which is not helpful.

I tried also to write $(u_n)$ in the exponential form but I could not proceed either.

What convergence criteria will be used in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it is a sequence, what want you to know?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I want to know if $\sum u_n$ converges or not.

Comment: Your first inequality is backwards, since $$u_n=\frac{5^n-3^n}{3^n+n^4}= \frac{5^n}{3^n+n^4}-\frac{3^n}{5^n+n^4}<\frac{5^n}{3^n+n^4}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a series $\sum u_n$ converges, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = 0$.

But
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{5^n - 3^n}{3^n + n^4 } = +\infty
$$
and so the series diverges.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: We get
$$\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{5^n-3^n}{3^n+n^4}=\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Your first inequality, that is, $u_n\geqslant\frac{5^n}{3^n+n^4}$, is a good starting point. Now, use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5^n}{3^n+n^4}}{\frac{5^n}{3^n}}=1.$$

Comment: I don't know how to derive the convergence of $\sum u_n$ from that. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi Use the [comparaison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).